# Meteor JS : Serve static files and persist query string

Tags: meteor

Suppose a user requests, domain.com/cat.png?user=name
All I want is to serve cat.png and log {user: name} to mongo.

I know I can host files in `/public/` but I need to record the query string params from the URL request, which is why I am using Iron Router's functions. I'm happy to do it any another way (without Iron router).

Below is my code adapted from other Stack Overflow responses.

```
//Added meteorhacks:npm

var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
var file = fs.readFileSync('/public/cat.png'); 


// Iron Router

Router.route('/', function() {
    // Return valid image.
   this.response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-type': 'image/png',
      'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + this.params.path
});
   this.response.end();

  //Run other tasks related to this download action
   myOtherFunctions();

 //Serve the file
   fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(this.response);
 });
```

Problem 1: I'm not even getting fs to find any files. For the example of public/cat.png the console complains:

> "Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/public/cat.png'"

Problem 2: If the file really exists in 'public' specifically, Meteor will override Iron Router's routes, and the events `myOtherFunctions()` will never run.

Comment: You do not need /public in front of your file. Just do '/cat.png'

Comment: Still same problem with '/cat.png' as you suggested. Are you not able to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
This is because `fs.readFileSync` needs absolute path for `public` directory. 
Something like `/home/User/yourMeteorApp/public/` + `yourFilename`

Problem 2
not a real problem

Try this on server:

```
PATH_FOR_YOUR_APP = "/home/User/ ..." //change it
Router.route('/:fileName', {where: 'server'})
  .get(function () {
    this.response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-type': 'image/png',
        'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + this.params.fileName
    });

    myOtherFunctions(); //here you look at query params and store {user: name} to mongo

    fs.createReadStream(PATH_FOR_YOUR_APP+"/public/"+this.params.fileName).pipe(this.response);
  })
```

Comment: This absolute path requirement is a problem. What's going to happen when deploying on production? Or collaborating with other developers?

Comment: This hack will work to get the absolute path for meteor, and remove the symlink: PATH_FOR_YOUR_APP = path.resolve('.', '../../../../../')